# "Пароль неправильный" даже при вводе правильного пароля PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Я новичок в PHP. Этот код выдает "The password is not valid." даже если я ввожу данные правильно. Что мне делать?

```
<?php

require_once "config.php";
require_once "session.php";


$error = '';
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST" && isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    $email = trim($_POST['email']);
    $password = trim($_POST['password']);
 
    // validate if email is empty
    if (empty($email)) {
        $error .= '<p class="error">Please enter email.</p>';
    }

    // validate if password is empty
    if (empty($password)) {
        $error .= '<p class="error">Please enter your password.</p>';
    }

    if (empty($error)) {
        if($query = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = ?")) {
            $query->bind_param('s', $email);
            $query->execute();
            $row = $query->fetch();
            if ($row) {
                if (password_verify($password, $row['password'])) {
                    $_SESSION["userid"] = $row['id'];
                    $_SESSION["user"] = $row;

                    // Redirect the user to welcome page
                    header("location: login.php");
                    exit;
                } else {
                    $error .= '<p class="error">The password is not valid.</p>';
                }
            } else {
                $error .= '<p class="error">No User exist with that email address.</p>';
            }
        }
        $query->close();
    }
    // Close connection
    mysqli_close($db);
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Login</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <h2>Login</h2>
                    <p>Please fill in your email and password.</p>
                    <?php echo $error; ?>
                    <form action="" method="post">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Email Address</label>
                            <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" required />
                        </div>    
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Password</label>
                            <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" required>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit">
                        </div>
                        <p>Don't have an account? <a href="register.php">Register here</a>.</p>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>    
    </body>
</html>
```

В чем может быть ошибка?

Comment: mysqli_close($db); у вас есть. а open?

Comment: `password_verify($password, $row['password'])` Смотрите, что пришло в `$password`, что в `$row['password']` и так же что происходит в `password_verify`. Функция `password_verify` возвращает **false**

Comment: От еще один, `$query->fetch()` __возвращает не то, что ты думаешь__.

Comment: а тогда как сделать правильно?

Comment: Читать [руководство](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/mysqli-stmt.fetch.php#refsect1-mysqli-stmt.fetch-returnvalues)